# How does a webapp save files to its server?

Tags: database, savechanges

I'm building a webapp where one can develop documents within the web browser (e.g., something like Zoho's document tool, or Google Docs). In my case, I have a set of arrays that store different paragraphs and other pieces of information, along with parallel arrays that store metadata on the paragraphs themselves.

The entire webapp is written in jQuery and associated libraries / plugins.

Is there an elegant way for me to save this as a file on the server itself? So far, I've been recommended using a hidden form to POST the arrays to the server and store them in a NoSQL database of some sort... This feels a bit painful to me and I'm wondering if (1) there is a more elegant approach, or (2) there is a library / framework that automates some of the sending / POSTing / saving.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create services that live on the server itself. These services would be methods such as (just as a simple example)

```
SaveDocument(User, Document) 
GetDocument(User, Document)
```

you would need to configure your web app to call these services and pass in the required parameters. Now as for how to do this, you could write the services in any number of languages  (Java using JavaEE, C# using WCF to name a few, but you can also do this in python/ruby/etc) and then generate WSDL interfaces to the services that any number of other languages could call.

There are lots of resources available on the web that cover this, so pick a language you want to learn, or are already proficient in and google around on how to develop web services in that language.

Good luck!